# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert com...DocumentType@24 of type class com...DocumentType to class java.lang.Boolean

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jsf, richfaces

I am gettting the error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert com...DocumentType@XX of type class com...DocumentType to class java.lang.Boolean
> only when I try to display my documents.jsf page

**NOTE**: This only happens when the foreign key (document_type_id)in the table **document** has a non-null value. If the value is NULL it works fine.
Here are the details -

The full stack error -

```
[2022 05 06 14:18:30,800]-[ERROR] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/stars].[Faces Servlet] :: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert com.csatf.stars.domain.dictionary.DocumentType@24 of type class com.csatf.stars.domain.dictionary.DocumentType to class java.lang.Boolean
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToBoolean(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.toString(ELText.java:174)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.toString(ELText.java:115)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.CommentInstruction.write(CommentInstruction.java:38)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:39)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:280)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:262)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:284)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:262)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:284)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.encodeCellChildren(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:283)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.ColgroupRenderer.encodeChildren(ColgroupRenderer.java:98)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:527)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:282)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.encodeCellChildren(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:283)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractTableRenderer.encodeOneRow(AbstractTableRenderer.java:225)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.process(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:87)
    at org.ajax4jsf.model.SequenceDataModel.walk(SequenceDataModel.java:101)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.walk(UIDataAdaptor.java:968)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.encodeRows(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:104)
    at org.richfaces.renderkit.AbstractRowsRenderer.encodeChildren(AbstractRowsRenderer.java:136)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:527)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.renderChild(RendererUtils.java:414)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.renderChildren(RendererUtils.java:400)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlGroupRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlGroupRendererBase.java:78)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:539)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:286)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:143)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:86)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:134)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:86)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:134)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:86)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:134)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:86)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:134)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:86)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:134)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:86)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:134)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:86)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:134)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:86)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:134)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:86)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:134)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:86)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:134)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxChildren(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:86)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxChildrenRenderer.encodeAjaxComponent(AjaxChildrenRenderer.java:134)
    at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.AjaxContainerRenderer.encodeAjax(AjaxContainerRenderer.java:122)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIAjaxRegion.encodeAjax(UIAjaxRegion.java:239)
    at org.ajax4jsf.context.AjaxContextImpl.renderAjaxRegion(AjaxContextImpl.java:289)
    at org.ajax4jsf.context.AjaxContextImpl$2.invoke(AjaxContextImpl.java:204)
    at org.ajax4jsf.context.JsfOneOneInvoker.invokeOnComponent(JsfOneOneInvoker.java:78)
    at org.ajax4jsf.context.JsfOneOneInvoker.invokeOnComponent(JsfOneOneInvoker.java:83)
    at org.ajax4jsf.context.AjaxContextImpl.invokeOnComponent(AjaxContextImpl.java:160)
    at org.ajax4jsf.context.AjaxContextImpl.renderSubmittedAjaxRegion(AjaxContextImpl.java:218)
    at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:239)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:132)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.csatf.stars.ui.filters.IE8CompatablityFixFilter.doFilterInternal(IE8CompatablityFixFilter.java:17)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.csatf.stars.ui.filters.RendererFilter.doFilterInternal(RendererFilter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.csatf.stars.ui.filters.EntityReattachmentFilter.doFilterInternal(EntityReattachmentFilter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:141)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:359)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:116)
    at com.csatf.stars.common.AjaxRememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AjaxRememberMeProcessingFilter.java:33)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:268)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:879)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
```

The **document** table -

```sql
id BIGINT primary key
document_type_id BIGINT foreign key document_type(id)
```

The **document_type** table -

```sql
id BIGINT primary key
code VARCHAR    
is_disabled BOOLEAN
```

The JSF code in the documents xhmtl -

```
<h:outputText
      value=" #{documentsBean.currentRecord.documentType.code}" />
```

The JSF code in the documents edit xhtml

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="documentTypeInput"
           validator="#{actionBean.validateDocumentType}"
            value="#{actionBean.modifiedRecord.documentType}"
            converter="#{documentTypeConverter}" required="true">
     <f:selectItems value="#{actionBean.documentTypeItems}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The documents Bean -

```java
public class DocumentsBean extends BaseTableBean<Document> {
    ....
}
```

The document entity -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOCUMENT")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Document extends AbstractModifiedEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
    private DocumentType documentType;

    public DocumentType getDocumentType() {
        return documentType;
    }

    public void setDocumentType(DocumentType documentType) {
        this.documentType = documentType;
    }
}
```

The document type entity -

```
    public class DocumentType extends AbstractModifiedEntity{
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "DOCUMENT_TYPE")
    public class DocumentType extends AbstractEntity {

            @Column(name = "CODE", length = CODE_LEN, nullable = false, unique = true)
            protected String code;

            @Column(name = "IS_DISABLED", nullable = false)
            private boolean disabled = false;

            public DocumentType() {
            }

            protected DocumentType(Long id) {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public String getCode() {
                return code;
            }

            public void setCode(String code) {
                this.code = code;
            }

            public boolean isDisabled() {
                return disabled;
            }

            public void setDisabled(boolean disabled) {
                this.disabled = disabled;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `h:outputText` is the only place where you reference the DocumentType? I don't see why it would be trying to convert DocumentType to boolean, especially if the expression is `documentType.code` which is a String.

Comment: Makhiel, on the documents page there is a list of documents where each document has a document type. And on that page there is an edit link which will bring up a dialog/panel where you can change the document type of the document selected. The document type on the dialog/panel is a drop-down of all the document types. `value="#{actionBean.modifiedRecord.documentType}"`

Comment: I mean dropdown menu shouldn't need to convert to boolean either, I recommend copying the page and removing components until you can pinpoint the problem.

Comment: took out the validator and the Document Bean complained about it missing. Then I took out the converter and the drop-down of document types was not populated. A strange thing is that the converter for the Document Type is not called (I put in debugs).